# Emberjs templating and routing

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-cli

So I have a regular website that I built in Emberjs. Now I want to add an admin to the app. The problem I'm facing is that the header for the app is in `application.hbs` but for the admin I want the header to be different. the header needs to stay in the `application.hbs` because of the urls need to be `/about` not `user/about` or what ever arent route I could create. I tried making the header a component and add it to the route that worked but it loses the webapp feel since the header leaves from route to route. Is there a way for me not to extend the application template in admin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I have understood your question, you are looking for having different headers for admin and non-admin routes without converting the header as a component. If so, then you can achieve it by using a flag in the application handlebar say, "isAdmin". For example:

In the application.hbs

```
{{#if isAdmin}}
    <h2>Header for Admin Route</h2>
    <button {{action "goToApp"}}> Go To Application </button>
    {{outlet "admin"}}
{{else}}
    <h2>Header for Application Routes</h2>
    <button {{action "goToAdmin"}}> Go To Admin Panel </button>
   {{outlet "app"}}
{{/if}}
```

Here "isAdmin" will be property in "ApplicationController". And, you can set this flag inside the "activate" and "deactivate" handlers of the route.

In the route/admin.js

```
   activate: function () {
      this.controllerFor("application").set("isAdmin", true);
    },
   deactivate: function () {
     this.controllerFor("application").set("isAdmin", false);
   },
   renderTemplate: function () {
    this.render({
      outlet: "admin"
    });
  }
```

Working JSBIN: http://jsbin.com/yilipa/edit?html,js,output

I hope this satisfies your requirement. If I have misunderstood your question, please do correct me.